# Inverting the exponential decay equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How would I algebraically isolate $x$ in the following exponential decay equation, so that $x$ is most easily derived?

$$
y = A e^{-\lambda x} \quad
$$

Comment: Do you know about logarithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply $\log$ on both sides :

$$\log(y) = \log(Ae^{-\lambda x}) = \log(A) + \log(e^{-\lambda x}) = \log(A)  -\lambda x\log(e) = \log(A) - \lambda x.$$

Therefore (if $\lambda \neq 0$) we got $$x = \frac{\log(A) - \log(y)}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Thanks! If y=0 is this solution still valid?

Comment: If $y = 0$ then $A$ must be 0 since the exponential function is never 0.

Comment: The logarithm is not defined at 0, i.e. $\log(0)$ does not exists.

Comment: If $y = 0$ we cannot say anything about $x$ since $A := 0$ is "killing" the expression $A e^{-\lambda x}$ in the sense that $0\cdot e^{-\lambda x} = 0$ no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. It was a Constant, independent of the decay equation, that was making my y=0.

Comment: That is correct.